# 2d 10:00:00 to TimeSpan in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, timespan

It's possible somehow to convert something like:

2d 10:00:00

To TimeSpan in c#?
There is already some function that converts it?

Some other examples could be:

```
30d 00:00:00
1m 3d 20:00:01
1y 2d 00:00:00
```

Or even Just:

```
3d
10d
3m
3y 10d
```

Comment: Use a bit of multiplication to solve for total seconds and call `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(double)` , Here's the Msdn page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromseconds?view=net-5.0

Comment: @asawyer What's the conversion for months to seconds?

Comment: There wouldn't be a clear way to convert years or months into a TimeSpan unless you know what year or what months those are because of leap years and the fact that not all months have the same number of days.

Comment: If you need to parse the months or years strings, you could use the `Period` type in [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/) instead of a `TimeSpan`.  You'd do the parsing with the `PeriodPattern` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Days, hours, minutes, and seconds are easy, as long as you've got a well-defined input format:

```
string input = "2d 10:00:00";
Timespan parsedTimespan = TimeSpan.ParseExact(input, @"d\d\ hh\:mm\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

As others have pointed out, Months, Years, etc. would be contextual. Technically days could be too, but in this case "days" always equates to 24 hours, regardless of your calendar.

To support other formats, like "2d", you'd probably have to write your own parsing code based on a spec that you come up with. Frameworks like Sprache can help if that gets very complicated.

Answer (score 3):

`TimeSpan` has very limited parsing abilities, and only goes up to days (not months or years). Another complexity is that some of these spans are context-dependent. A `3m` span starting in Feb (which has a 28/29 and a 30-day month) is different than a `3m` span starting in July (which has 2 31-day months).

So it depends on what you want to *do* with the span to determine the best way to parse. At some point you'll have to split the string by spaces and convert the `Nm` and `Ny` components to a number of days, adding the parsed time string component (`hh:mm:ss`) to that to generate a total `TimeSpan`.

Comment: I see, so it would be viabler to just limit that to days? Like 30d 00:00:00
Edit: Typo

Comment: @VitorSobrinho - That is correct. It's not possible to do months without first knowing which specific month you're dealing with (and I don't just mean "Feb", you'd need the year as well). Starting at the month level, your length of time is not constant any longer.